# Inconsistent result with sqlite delete command with limit enabled

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here are my sqlite db details,

```
sqlite> .table
url_db
sqlite> .schema url_db
CREATE TABLE url_db(URL TEXT UNIQUE);
sqlite> select * from url_db;
play.googleapis.com
notifications.google.com
contacts.skype.com
edge.skype.com
people.skype.com
```

I wanted to execute the command `delete from url_db limit 1`.

So I've downloaded the full source code (sqlite-src-3240000.zip) from the [official download page](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html).

Compiled the source code with the option 'SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT=1'

When I execute that command (command executed), sometimes it deletes the random entry but not the first entry. I wanted to delete `play.googleapis.com`, instead that command deleted `contacts.skype.com`.

```
sqlite> select * from url_db;
play.googleapis.com
notifications.google.com
edge.skype.com
people.skype.com
```

What's the cause for this behavior? I am implementing a FIFO list in which when the entries reach 500, I need to delete the first entry.

Comment: I am guessing that you will continue to get a "random" deletion, unless you specifically order the records before deleting the first one. So... include an `order by` clause as well as the `limit` clause.

Comment: Tables in a relational database are **NOT** sorted in any way. The **only** way (really: the only) way to get a guaranteed sort order is to use an `order by` in your `select` statement. The same is true for a `delete` with a limit - if you can't specify an order then the row that is picked is chosen "randomly"

Comment: Actually this db is storing URLs timely basis. I need to delete the oldest URL which stored in db first. As @peter says, I can't oder by asc or desc order. Or is there any way I can order the db by time and then delete URLs?

Comment: What you can do is the following: Add a column which has a value that will definitely increase for every added record (auto-incremented ID, time-stamp, ...), and then order (DESC) by that column, before deleting with limit 1.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a new column already which stores time stamp. Then I would get the lowest time stamp and then I would delete the entire row. I just wanted to make that `delete from table limit 1` command work properly. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> sometimes it deletes the random entry but not the first entry.

You misunderstand relational databases.  A table represents an *unordered* set.  There is no "first" row in a table, unless you explicitly define the ordering.

Because this problem occurs so often, SQLite has a built-in work-around, the `rowid` "column".  You can use this as a regular column, resulting in:

```
delete from url_db
    order by rowid
    limit 1;
```

Personally, I prefer an explicitly declared auto-increment column, but SQLite builds in this functions (unlike other databases).